# Wordpress connect

Tags: php, html, wordpress, xhtml, mysqli

I'm a newbie in WordPress. I'm trying to read information from a custom table in the database and display it on a form, however my SQL statement is not working. What could I have missed here? Other scripts are already working. Here is my code.

```
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wk2012_zipcodes" );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way and let me know if it works.

```
global $wpdb;
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->zipcodes" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "wk2012" is your table prefix, you don't have to hardcode it, use instead :

```
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->zipcodes" );
```